# iOS repositioning views like when moving apps

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, view

I'm developing an iOS app where I have a grid of views (3x4).

I would like to be able to move them like apps: make a longpress so all start to shake and then you can move the views where you want, and the others reposition.

I know how to detect the long press and how to animate the view, but how can views move altogether to make place for the view you move? (just like apps do).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is break it down into multiple steps. First, calculate two states for each view in the grid. The before position and the after position. Core animation will handle the intermediate animations of how to get from the before  state to the after state. Because you are dragging a view, you need to detect which row,col the view being dragged is closest to and when it enters that area, fire the animation. This process is repeated until the user lets go, which is when the view moves to the final row,col and the process is finished.

Comment: But how the other views know where to go and how do you know wich view is in each place? Is there any tutorial or open source code, because it sounds a little bit difficult.

Comment: What are you using to make your grid? Are you using autolayout or manually laying out the views? If you are using a 3rd party framework, it's -layoutSubviews method should be where the placement of each view is calculated. If you are doing the layout work yourself, you simply need to shift the views one place over. The views after the index that the view shift +1, the views before the index where the insertion is occurring keep the same location.

Comment: So how can I detect wich views have to move? Can I call a view with its position? With CGREct? Can you make a little code explanation?